# Ошибка в записывании даты в postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, дата

Входные данные:2017-03-15

```
    String date="2017-03-15";
    LocalDate localedate = LocalDate.parse(   date  );
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, localedate.getYear());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, localedate.getMonthValue());
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, localedate.getDayOfMonth());
    date1 = cal.getTime();
```

На выходе я получаю - Sat Apr 15 16:12:47 GMT+02:00 2017.
Почему с месяцем ошибка?
2-й момент: я записываю дату в postgresql, а мне в бд записывается не только дата но и время. Как этого избежать.
Для справки: тип столбца в postgresql, я использую date. В документации написано - дата **(без времени суток)**. В Pojo которое маппиться на таблицу использую соответственно java.util.Date

Answer (score 1):

Из документации на LocalDate getMonthValue() возвращает значение месяца от 1 до 12, для Calendar же set(Calendar.MONTH, ...) принимает значения месяца от 0, см. Calendar.JANUARY и т.д.

java.util.Date -- содержит дату и время, если в БД сохраняется только дата, то после чтения из БД ваше поля типа java.util.Date будет содержать дату и 00:00:00. Чтобы избежать используйте сразу LocalDate.

Comment: Спасибо! Почти получилось, только замена Data на тип LocalDate работает на 50%, в куче все хорошо. Но при записи в PostgreSql пишет:Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "date_when" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bytea
  Подсказка: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: Все, проблему решил.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы хотите использовать свой способ записи даты, вы можете его указать с помощью DateFormat который принимает формат который будет записываться в переменную

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date myNewDate = dateFormat.parse(new Date);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```